# Kamailio Server- Internal Server error

Tags: sip, sdp, kamailio

I am trying to establish a chat session(MSRP) with two sipclients endpoints by registering to kamailio server(4.0.0), but I am getting `500 Internal server error(Reason: SIP ;text="media stream failed to start" ;cause=500)`.
What might be the problem?? Does it mean that kamailio can not handle msrp session? If yes how to enable it in the server? Please help me in this regard.

```
Request-Line: INVITE sip:03271485@172.16.7.82:50666 SIP/2.0
Record-Route: sip:172.16.7.201;lr=on
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.16.7.201;branch=z9hG4bKce48.40d19c96.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.16.7.46:45669;rport=45669;
branch=z9hG4bKPj28UvXKngB3PjBBmoyrTFZXoeNcVx4oIm
Max-Forwards: 16
From: sip:511@172.16.7.201;tag=-4TgMXfcfaV0Cj5VnCIxOkL1QmHji8PL
To: sip:411@172.16.7.201
Contact: sip:80945273@172.16.7.46:45669
Call-ID: bpOWizGe-SHsjIZXSLKptnnDBVi7dMnY
CSeq: 3687 INVITE
Allow: SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, MESSAGE, REFER
Supported: 100rel, replaces, norefersub, gruu
User-Agent: sipsimple 1.3.0
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:297
v=0
o=- 3612147894 3612147894 IN IP4 172.16.7.46
s=sipsimple 1.3.0
c=IN IP4 172.16.7.46
t= 0 0
m=message 2855 TCP/TLS/MSRP *
a=path:msrps://172.16.7.46:2855/7ad200ec7137e5ed1a58;tcp
a=accept-types:message/cpim text/* application/im-iscomposing+xml
a=accept-wrapped-types:*
a=setup:active
Status-Line: SIP/2.0 500 Internal Server Error
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.16.7.201;received=172.16.7.201;branch=z9hG4bKce48.40d19c96
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.16.7.46:45669;rport=45669 branch=z9hG4bKPj28UvXKngB3PjBBmoyrTFZXoeNcVx4oIm
Record-Route: <sip:172.16.7.201;lr>
Call-ID: bpOWizGe-SHsjIZXSLKptnnDBVi7dMnY
From: sip:511@172.16.7.201;tag=-4TgMXfcfaV0Cj5VnCIxOkL1QmHji8PL
To: sip:411@172.16.7.201;tag=XKuUttlVFnfBakd5ATHkw9nhmIEOtCL2
CSeq:3687 INVITE
Server: sipsimple 1.3.0
AllowSUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, MESSAGE, REFER
Reason: SIP ;text=\"media stream failed to start\" ;cause=500
Content-Length:  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I could not establish MSRP session through a relay, I could establish the session between the endpoints. In Sipclients, msrp.connection_model should be set to "acm" for end to end msrp session. So I can say that it is not a problem with kamailio server